# remove duplicate lines (or regex emails ) from a 1TB Text file , using c# ? memory exeption

Tags: c#

```
   string[] linesm = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialogP.FileName);
                File.WriteAllLines(tCorrectFileName.Text, linesm.Distinct().ToArray());
```

string[] linesm = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);
File.WriteAllLines(tCorrectFileName.Text, linesm.Distinct().ToArray());

Answer (score 0):

Reading the entire file into memory would require more than a terabyte of memory, so it's perhaps unsurprising you're running out of memory..

You'll have to read this file line by line and write a new file line by line. Extract the email address of the current line, and (using something like a HashSet to keep track of email addresses you've already seen) if you already saw the email, don't write the line to the new file

Comment: tnx bro ,you are right about email regex. as i mentioned i understand the memory Problem , and i wrote it to avoid some body came here to write (Like My simple easy code) but there is still problem in remove duplicate. i think , i have to use mssql or something like this!

Comment: If you have another code that does the same, post it so we can see :) maybe it will work better when the bugs are removed